# How to retrieve data from API Explorer?

Tags: python, html, xml, api, web-scraping

My question is more in the "concept" side, as I don't have any code to show yet. I've basically got access to an API Explorer for a website, but the information retrieved when I put a specific url in the API Explorer is not the same as the html information I'd get if I opened a webpage with the same url and "inspected" the elements. I'm honestly lost on how to retrieve the data I need, as they are only present in the API Explorer but can't be accessible via web scraping.

Here is an example to show you what I mean:

API Explorer link: https://platform.worldcat.org/api-explorer/apis/worldcatidentities/identity/Read,

and the specific url to request is: http://www.worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n80126307/

If I put the url (http://www.worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n80126307/) myself and "inspect element", this piece of information:

[image: html version]

does not have all the same data as:

[image: API Explorer]

For example, the language count, audLevel, oclcnum and many others are not existent in the html version but are in the API Explorer and with other authors, the genres count is only existent in the API Explorer.

I realize that one is in xml and the other in html so is that why the data is not the same in both versions? And whatever is the reason, what can I do to retrieve the data present only in the API Explorer? (such as genres count, audLevel, oclcnum, etc.)

Any insight would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not unusual for sites not showing all the data, that's in the underlying json/xml. Those sorts of things often holds interesting content that aren't displayed anywhere onsite.

In this case the server gives you, what you ask for. If you're going for the data using Python, all you really have to do is specify in your header what you're after. If you don't do that on this site, you get the html-stuff.

If you do like this, you'll get the xml data, you're interested in:

```
import requests
import xml.dom.minidom

url = 'https://www.worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n80126307/'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept': 'application/json'})

# a couple of lines for printing the xml pretty
xml = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(r.text)
pretty_xml_as_string = xml.toprettyxml()
print(pretty_xml_as_string)
```

Then all you have to do is extract the content, you're after. That can be done in many ways. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helps! Out of curiosity, how do you get the output to use newlines? My output has all the xml in one single line. And also, what possible ways are there to extract the content? I've seen other posts suggesting fromstring(xml).find(), but I'm not really sure how it goes.

Comment: I updated the answer with a couple of lines for pretty printing xml. If you need help on extracting data please review some of the many answers already given on SO on the subject. If none of these helps you further open a new question where you showcase your attempts to do it. I'm sure someone will help you from there once you've demonstrated that you actually put an effort into it first...